# Кросплатформенный путь получения папки, в которой можно хранить файлы приложения

Tags: c++, пути, кроссплатформенность

В *Linux*, например, такой папкой будет `/home/user_name/.app_name`, а в *Windows* - папка `AppData`.

Как кросплатформенно получить путь к директории, в которой можно создать папку `.app_name` и хранить файлы приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хочется кроссплатформенности - нужно смотреть в сторону кроссплатформенных же библиотек, например *Qt*. Там это будет что-то типа [`QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html).

На уровне языка никаких папок с файлами приложений не существует. Даже после добавления в стандартную библиотеку [`filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs), Вам придётся опираться на какие-то настройки ОС.

Answer (score 2):

Такой класс есть - [QStandardPaths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html). Там приведены примеры реальных путей - выбирайте то, что Вам нужно. Да, для этого придется переехать на Qt:)

Comment: А исходные коды есть у `QStandardPaths`? А то переезжать совсем не охота.

Comment: @pank: А там небось набор `#ifdef`'ов.

Comment: Исходный код Qt открыт. Только вряд ли вам удастся выдернуть из него функции, так как они зависят от других классов фреймворка, и зависимости могут быть очень глубокими.

Comment: можно без пачкти ifdef. все очень легко делается:)

Comment: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/io/qstandardpaths.cpp

Comment: @maestro, согласен, исходные коды мало чем помогли.

Comment: @KoVadim: Наверное, можно, но по факту: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/io/qstandardpaths.cpp#L462, https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/io/qstandardpaths.cpp#L545

Answer (score 2):

Навскидку 2 варианта:

1. C: `getenv("HOME")`
2. Java: `System.getProperty("user.home");`

Comment: А на *Windows*?